# Configure Navigation Inheritance when create site with Rest API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, rest

I wonder how do I keep the navigation bar of the parent site when I create a subsite. Below is the code I'm using to create the subsite and thought it might be some parameter that I could use to do that.

The code I am using works and the subsite are created correctly but not with the parent navigation bar.

Any idea? Thanks.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos/add",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(
        {
            'parameters': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation' },
                'Url': urlName,
                'Title': title,
                'Description': description,
                'Language': 1046,
                'WebTemplate': template,
                'UseUniquePermissions': false
            }
        }
    ),
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {

    }
});
```

Edited:
Example code to change UseShared. It works, I get the alert success but nothing changes.

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/Web/Navigation/UseShared",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'UseShared': true }),
    headers: {
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "IF-MATCH": "*"
    },
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});
function onSuccess(data) {
    alert("Pass request.");
}
function onError(errorMessage) {
    alert("Erro = " + errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? After we changed the masterpage using REST, the UseShared settings is somehow set to false. We really like to reapply shared navigation after the masterpage is set.

Comment: No I dont, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [scalar properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh630062%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to SP.WebInfoCreationInformation there is no parameter for that. The available properties are the ones you use. So you'll probably have to make another call after the web is created, and set the [UseShared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd958988%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Navigation to true.

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks for the reply. You can show an example code how can I do that?

Comment: I try a code (updated in post) but nothing change and I have no response from my request. What is wrong?

Comment: Hey, tbh I'm not sure whats wrong. If you could use the CSOM instead of rest, this would be much easier. Did a quick search, and checked the docs. But could not find much on REST and Navigation

Comment: I update the code above with my request. Now he make the request and I got the response but not change...

Answer (score 1):

After some researches, here is the solution... Using the "old" JSOM

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext("YOUR SITE URL");
var currentWeb = context.get_web();
var navigation = currentWeb.get_navigation();
navigation.set_useShared(true);
context.executeQueryAsync(function () { alert("Navigation Modification Successful"); });
```